# Is coupling reaction performed in acidic or basic medium?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, amines

Why is coupling reaction between aryldiazonium chloride and aniline carried out in a mild basic medium and not under acidic medium?
According to me, it can be performed in both mediums.